# How To Disable Curl Debug Output in PHP

Tags: php, http, curl, debugging, header

I wrote a PHP CUrl Class, if i execute Methods which should return the Content, it returns at first the Headers and after that the Content. So i cant parse any XML Data.
I need to Disable This Sample Output.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 01 Apr 2010 20:11:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny4 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny4
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=44beccf62f87546140d4a0bd24bd28b0; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/xml
```

Here is The Curl Class

```
<?php

class Test_Curl
{
    protected $curl;
    protected $headers;
    protected $useragent;
    protected $url;
    protected $testkey;

    public function  __construct()
    {

    }

    public function setUseraget($useragent)
    {
        $this->useragent = $useragent;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setApiKey($key)
    {

        $this->billomatApiKey   = $key;
    }

    private function curlExecGeneral()
    {
        $result     = curl_exec($this->curl);
        curl_close($this->curl);
        return $result;
    }



    private function curlInitGeneral($request)
    {
        $this->curl = curl_init($request);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-testkey: ".$this->testkey, "Content-Type: application/xml"));
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    }

    public function get($request)
    {
        $this->curlInitGeneral($request);
        curl_setopt ($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
        return $this->curlExecGeneral();
    }

    public function post($request, $xml)
    {
        $this->curlInitGeneral($request);
        curl_setopt ($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); //set the Requestmethod to POST
        curl_setopt ($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml); //add the xml data to the Request
        return $this->curlExecGeneral();
    }



}
?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [cURL options](http://fi.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
```